# See if user clicked back button?

Tags: java, android, string

### TL;DR: How do I know if the ad is open while the use pressed the back button?

I am trying to reward a user a point whenever they watch/look at an ad. I give the user the reward whenever they watch the ad. However, the user earns a point even if they go to the ad and click back:

```
 mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                giveUserPoint();
                }
            }
        });
```

Is there a way I can see if the user clicked the back button **while** the ad was opened? Maybe something like:

```
  userBackClickListener(){
    if(adIsOpen){
dontGiveUserPoint();
    }
}
```

How can I see if the ad was open while an action happened?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather check when you are calling onAdClosed. Maybe is best to fire the event when the ad ends, so if user goes back before that, nothing happens.

Comment: How do I fire it when the ad ends?

Comment: Right now, I just have the listener declared in my `onCreate()`.

Comment: Who is using your listener? Are you implementing any library?

Comment: I'm just using the default AdMob interstitial. My listener is declared in `onCreate`, and I have posted it at the top of my question. The interstitial object is using the listener, which is why it is defined like **mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()**. Please let me know how to fire it when the ad ends. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//code
}
```